# Wrongly created folder including main project file

Tags: xcode

I have wrongly created new folder like this. How shall I remove that folder back and make it back to normal ?

[image]

If I drag it back, it say to save as new project. But I can't go back to normal.

[image]

Comment: No :( It say to save as new project. but after I did, it also never go back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I have removed my main project (just remove reference) and I close that one. After that, I open my project file again and add the project as new file. Then, that project become top and new folder is auto-deleted. Luckily, I get back.